# Report matching status of all characters in a phrase with all characters in an alphabet

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have the following method in Java:

```
void searchPhrase(String[] phrase){
        searchResult = new int[phrase.length];
        int j=0, k=0;
        for (int i=0; i<frase.length;i++)
            if (!phrase[i].equals(alphabet[k])){
                System.out.println("\nLetter "+phrase[i]+" was not found when comparing it to "+alphabet[k]);
                k++;
            }
            else{               
                System.out.println("\nLetter "+phrase[i]+" was found when comparing it to "+alphabet[k]);
                searchResult[j] = i;
                k=0;
            }
    }
```

I have two String arrays, phrase and alphabet. Phrase is any given phrase, and alphabet contains the alphabet from A to Z.
I need the method to receive a phrase, let's say: "HELLO STACK". Then, it must compare every letter to the alphabet, like this:
   H == A? No.
   H == B? No.
... 
   H == H? Yes 
     Then, searchResult[0] = 7, because letter H from phrase[i] was equal to alphabet[7]. Now that it's found letter H, it should go on with letter E, and so on. 
Unfortunately, my code is doing this:
   H == A? No.
   E == B? No.
   L == C? No.
   L == D? No.
   O == E? No.
   *(blank space)*  == F? No.
   S == G? No.
and it goes on until it completes the phrase "HELLO STACK". What can I do to stop it from going onto the next letter if it is not found in the alphabet? 
Many Thanks!

Comment: at for loop I saw "frase.length". It's another variable?

Comment: Why aren't you using `String.indexOf()`?

Comment: @user3651293 answer posted for you acceptance with output

Comment: It was a mistake, it should also have been "phrase.length".

Comment: Back away from the computer. Get a paper and pencil and write the steps that you need to solve this problem. (OK, you can use a word processor if you want.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood what you want to do, the code should be:

```
void searchPhrase(String[] phrase){
    searchResult = new int[phrase.length];
    int j=0;
    for (int i=0; i<frase.length;i++){
        for (int k=0; k<alphabet.length;k++){        
            if (!phrase[i].equals(alphabet[k])){
                System.out.println("\nLetter "+phrase[i]+" was not found when comparing it to "+alphabet[k]);
                k++;
            }
            else{               
                System.out.println("\nLetter "+phrase[i]+" was found when comparing it to "+alphabet[k]);
                searchResult[j] = i;
                k=0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested the code, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks!!! It worked just fine, I only removed the k++ inside the if, because the alphabet was A, C, F, H... THANKS!!!

Answer (score 1):

To get that logic, [*use another (nested) loop*](http://www.kirkwood.edu/pdf/uploaded/262/nestedloops.pdf).

The outer loop iterates over the characters in the phrase (as done) and the inner loop iterates the characters in the alphabet. "Stopping it from going onto the next letter" is done when the inner loop (which loops over the alphabet) terminates because it matched the current phrase character. Then the next iteration of the outer loop continues and so on, until the phrase is done being iterated.

Using [`break`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) (the example code also shows using nested loops) will be helpful when/if using an `if` inside the inner loop. Also, depending on the assignment, it may be required to handle the case when a character in the phrase isn't in the alphabet. Once the task is completed using a regular loop, see [ehanced for loops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) which can clean up the code as no index must be fiddled with.

Comment: Thanks! I did it that way and it worked. Thanks for the presentation as well.

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want to continue if `phrase[n] != alphabet[k]` then the phrase would always need to be 'abc.....' because if you use `HELLO STACK` the first letter is `H` which is `!= alphabet[0](A)`.

you can use a nested loop here

is your phrase an array? do you have several phrase? if not this would be the function

i prefer to make the alphabet array to be `char[] alphabet`

```
void searchPhrase(String phrase){

 //string length()
 outer:
 for(int x = 0 ; x < phrase.length() ; x++){
     //char length
     inner:
     for(int y = 0 ; y < alphabet.length ; y++){

         if(phrase.charAt(x) == alphabet[y]){
            //alphabet found
         }else{
            //not found
         break outer;
         }
     }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
void searchPhrase(String[] phrase){
            searchResult = new int[phrase.length];
            int j=0, m=-1, n=-1;
            for (int i=0; i<phrase.length;i++)
            {
              for (int k=0; i<26;i++)
              {
                if (phrase[i].equals(alphabet[k]))
                {
                 searchPhrase[i] = k;    
                 System.out.println("\nLetter "+phrase[i]+" was found when comparing it to"+alphabet[k]);
                }
               }
             }
```

Answer (score 1):

Working example, use both String array to match

```
public static void searchPhrase(String[] phrase) {
        int[] searchResult = new int[phrase.length];
        String[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < phrase.length ; i++)
            for (int k = 0 ; k < alphabet.length ; k++) {
                if (!phrase[i].toLowerCase().equals(alphabet[k])) {
                    System.out.println("\nLetter " + phrase[i] + " was not found when comparing it to " + alphabet[k]);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("\nLetter " + phrase[i] + " was found when comparing it to " + alphabet[k]);
                    searchResult[j] = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
```

**Output**

```
Letter H was not found when comparing it to 

Letter H was not found when comparing it to a

Letter H was not found when comparing it to b

Letter H was not found when comparing it to c

Letter H was not found when comparing it to d

Letter H was not found when comparing it to e

Letter H was not found when comparing it to f

Letter H was not found when comparing it to g

Letter H ** was found when comparing it to ** h

Letter E was not found when comparing it to 

Letter E was not found when comparing it to a

Letter E was not found when comparing it to b

Letter E was not found when comparing it to c

Letter E was not found when comparing it to d

Letter E ** was found when comparing it to ** e

Letter L was not found when comparing it to 

Letter L was not found when comparing it to a

Letter L was not found when comparing it to b

Letter L was not found when comparing it to c

Letter L was not found when comparing it to d

Letter L was not found when comparing it to e

Letter L was not found when comparing it to f

Letter L was not found when comparing it to g

Letter L was not found when comparing it to h

Letter L was not found when comparing it to i

Letter L was not found when comparing it to j

Letter L was not found when comparing it to k

Letter L ** was found when comparing it to ** l

Letter L was not found when comparing it to 

Letter L was not found when comparing it to a

Letter L was not found when comparing it to b

Letter L was not found when comparing it to c

Letter L was not found when comparing it to d

Letter L was not found when comparing it to e

Letter L was not found when comparing it to f

Letter L was not found when comparing it to g

Letter L was not found when comparing it to h

Letter L was not found when comparing it to i

Letter L was not found when comparing it to j

Letter L was not found when comparing it to k

Letter L ** was found when comparing it to ** l

Letter O was not found when comparing it to 

Letter O was not found when comparing it to a

Letter O was not found when comparing it to b

Letter O was not found when comparing it to c

Letter O was not found when comparing it to d

Letter O was not found when comparing it to e

Letter O was not found when comparing it to f

Letter O was not found when comparing it to g

Letter O was not found when comparing it to h

Letter O was not found when comparing it to i

Letter O was not found when comparing it to j

Letter O was not found when comparing it to k

Letter O was not found when comparing it to l

Letter O was not found when comparing it to m

Letter O was not found when comparing it to n

Letter O ** was found when comparing it to ** o

Letter S was not found when comparing it to 

Letter S was not found when comparing it to a

Letter S was not found when comparing it to b

Letter S was not found when comparing it to c

Letter S was not found when comparing it to d

Letter S was not found when comparing it to e

Letter S was not found when comparing it to f

Letter S was not found when comparing it to g

Letter S was not found when comparing it to h

Letter S was not found when comparing it to i

Letter S was not found when comparing it to j

Letter S was not found when comparing it to k

Letter S was not found when comparing it to l

Letter S was not found when comparing it to m

Letter S was not found when comparing it to n

Letter S was not found when comparing it to o

Letter S was not found when comparing it to p

Letter S was not found when comparing it to q

Letter S was not found when comparing it to r

Letter S ** was found when comparing it to ** s

Letter T was not found when comparing it to 

Letter T was not found when comparing it to a

Letter T was not found when comparing it to b

Letter T was not found when comparing it to c

Letter T was not found when comparing it to d

Letter T was not found when comparing it to e

Letter T was not found when comparing it to f

Letter T was not found when comparing it to g

Letter T was not found when comparing it to h

Letter T was not found when comparing it to i

Letter T was not found when comparing it to j

Letter T was not found when comparing it to k

Letter T was not found when comparing it to l

Letter T was not found when comparing it to m

Letter T was not found when comparing it to n

Letter T was not found when comparing it to o

Letter T was not found when comparing it to p

Letter T was not found when comparing it to q

Letter T was not found when comparing it to r

Letter T was not found when comparing it to s

Letter T ** was found when comparing it to ** t

Letter A was not found when comparing it to 

Letter A ** was found when comparing it to ** a

Letter C was not found when comparing it to 

Letter C was not found when comparing it to a

Letter C was not found when comparing it to b

Letter C ** was found when comparing it to ** c

Letter K was not found when comparing it to 

Letter K was not found when comparing it to a

Letter K was not found when comparing it to b

Letter K was not found when comparing it to c

Letter K was not found when comparing it to d

Letter K was not found when comparing it to e

Letter K was not found when comparing it to f

Letter K was not found when comparing it to g

Letter K was not found when comparing it to h

Letter K was not found when comparing it to i

Letter K was not found when comparing it to j

Letter K ** was found when comparing it to ** k
```

Comment: @user2864740 dnt know, hot post output

Comment: Now just add `<!-- language: lang-none -->` above it so it's "colorless" (otherwise the language will be guessed).